# Xcode affectedByGravity value resets to true and will not stay set to false

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, field, gravity

I am fairly new to Xcode Games, but I have been trying to work with the gravitational fields. I am able to create the fields, make bodies interact with them etc, however, when I create a SKSpriteNode programmatically, the second I give it a physics body, no matter what I set the AffectedByGravity or the fieldBitMask value to, it is alway attracted to the radial field in the scene.

Here's the bit of code I think is relevant:

```
 func createNewBody(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat){
    let newBody = SKSpriteNode()
    newBody.texture = SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Circle_Burgundy_Solid.svg"))
    newBody.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    newBody.position.x = x
    newBody.position.y = y
    newBody.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: newBody.size.width/2)
    newBody.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(newBody)
}
```

This code is called from the touchedBegan method:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        if touch == touches.first{
            createNewBody(x: touch.location(in: self).x, y: touch.location(in: self).y)
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is not working. Any ideas would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I tried printing the value of newBody.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity in the update() method, and it returns optional(true) no matter where and when I set it to false even in the update() method.

Comment: So newBody in your method is a new sprite at the location they touched right?  There could be a whole bunch of them right?  Which newBody are you printing out in your update method?  Is there a global newBody stored somewhere that is different?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you used a local variable `newBody` are you sure that that node is available in `update`?

`affectedByGravity` is intended to defined the interaction with the while gravity of the physics world and is not related to any other field.

If you want to define the behaviour of a given node relatively to a field you need to set the `fieldBitMask` of the node and the `categoryBitMask` of the field accordingly.